# Cannot read property of undefined error when passing user data into meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor

I keep getting the following error:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined at Object.editable

I've been trying to debug it with no luck.

I'm trying to pass a user object into an editUser template. So when I click edit, and get the form, I'll be able to see the user previous values inside the input fields, but I cannot get the values to appear on the form.

Here is the code  I have now:

```
# users.js

// Helpers
Template.user.helpers({
    user: () => {
        let user =  Meteor.user() ? Meteor.user() : 'Unable to pull user info';
        return user
    },
    editable: function () {
        
        let currentUserId =  Meteor.user()._id;
        let currentUser =  Meteor.user();

        // let currentUserFind = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this._id});

        return Session.equals('editUser', currentUserId);
    }
});


# user.tpl.jade
// Events
Template.user.events({
    'click .form-edit'(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let currentUser=  Meteor.user({});
        let currentUserId =  Meteor.user()._id;
        let currentUserFind = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this._id});

        console.log(currentUserId); 
        console.log(currentUserFind);   
        // console.log(this._id);
        
        Session.set('editUser', currentUserId);
        // Session.set('editUser', this._id);
    }
});

if editable
    +editUser
else
    with currentUser
        .card.card--user
            h3.card__title= username
            p.card__content= profile.email
            p.card__content= profile.firstName
            p.card__content= profile.lastName
            p.card__content= profile.bio
            button.card__btn.form-edit Edit
```

I have tried passing the `id` and the user object but I cannot get the error to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this exception with `Meteor.user()._id` when you don't import the Meteor pseudo-global. Once you `import {Meteor}` the exception will disappear. `Meteor.userId()` will also do the work.

Comment: thanks the `Meteor.userId()` actually solved my error problem.  I'm still unable to see the user data inside my edit fields though. Know, how I could fix that? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your code but since you have a session helper with your current user you could use that in your template. For example if you want to pre-fill an input field with the name of the user you could have something like <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fullname" value="{{currentUser.profile.name}}" autofocus="true" placeholder="Full Name"> . By the way, meteor already provides you with the helper currentUser, you don't have to define it.

Comment: Hey man  thanks the `value='{{currentUser.profile.name}}'` inside the input field fixed my problem. I was trying to pass it as `value='{{user.profile.name}}'`, but wasn't able to  see anything. Do you know why that is?

PS: The last part of the code is just jade syntax, same as {{username}} in spacebars and blaze

Comment: Cool! Well, if you try to pass `{{user.profile.name}}` it will try to evaluate the `user` helper, which actually doesn't exist. Your helper is called `currentUser` and holds the information about the user object.

Comment: Would it work if I were to create a custom `user` helper? I know this is an overkill, just trying to understand the problem. But once again thanks man

Comment: Yes, so if you define a helper   `user() {return Meteor.user()}` and in your template you pass `{{user.profile.name}}` that should work.